# Encrypting database login information mySQL connector

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, encryption, jdbc

I'm new to programming and I am a little lost. I'm building a desktop app that upon being launched, prompts the user to log in and the app then connects to my sites mySQL database and verifies it and if the user is found, then a second JFrame appears and the user can now use the program.

I hadn't thought of that, but now I'm faced with the problem of someone decompiling the app and getting access to the mySQL connection details.

Here is a trimmed version of the connection code for reference.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class databaseConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    getConnection();
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbase";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, 
 username, password);
        System.out.println("Connected.");
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return null;

}
}
```

Is there a way to hide or encrypt the url, username and password? I understand nothing is absoluetly secure and this would just make it a tad harder for someone with malicious intent, but strasight up leaving the information for anyone to see seems a little foolish.

thanks

Comment: this is a bit... hard, you can resort on obfuscation.. or simply develop a server side app that have the direct connection to the database and authenticate user per-request. the later would be preferred as you can never trust end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to solve this issue, which is why you don't see that many desktop programs connecting to a central database (anymore). Any credentials contained inside your programs are visible. Sure, you can use any amount of time you want to invent "security schemes", but it won't change the fact that it's just insecure.

You have basically three ways to avoid that issues. Make your application a webapp so the users can't access the code, make your users set up their own databases with their own credentials (this obviously won't help if you want all users to be able to exchange information between each other) or thirdly, write a backend layer so the desktop clients don't connect to the database directly. They would then send commands to the backend to perform database operations, and you can control the backend credentials to allow connections to whom you want.